# FreeNAS remote shutdown

Tags: ssh, sudo, freenas, sudoers

I want to write a program that remotely shuts down my TrueNAS server.

When I enable sudo for the user `myuser`, the command `ssh myuser@hostname -t "sudo poweroff"` is actually enough.

But I don't want to give that user full sudo access, he should only be able to use the poweroff command. I can achieve this by modifying the `/etc/local/sudoers` file and adding the following line `myuser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /sbin/poweroff`. But as expected, this change isn't persisted over reboots.

How can I persist changes to the sudoer file (since more detailed sudo restrictions are not possible with TrueNAS configurations [according to the source code](https://github.com/truenas/freenas/blob/9187e5a0d9ce4a69932aaf73e3464eac97dac3d9/src/middlewared/middlewared/etc_files/local/sudoers.mako))?

Comment: There are various suggestions in the post [Poweroff or Reboot as normal User](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85663/poweroff-or-reboot-as-normal-user), but I don't know which ones will work in TrueNAS.